# After renewing IOS developer membership, my apps are "pending contract"

Tags: app-store-connect

I did the following
- renewed my company IOS developer program membership, as it was expiring soon
- changed agent contact details, as the previous agent had left the company.

What happened:
- Apple removed my company's apps from store, dropped them to "pending contract" state.

I next
- released an updated version of the app with bugfixes, it passed Apple review and I published

what happened:
- Apple put the new version also to "Pending contract" state.

What happened next:
- I look at the "banking and tax information" from Itunes Connect
- it says IOS membership has expired.
- I go to membership center and check and it is expiring 2014..

I hate apple for not offering me way to escalate this situation to them to be able to resolve this.

does anyone else experience similar difficulties? Is there any way for me to contact apple and let them know I am experiencing this?

Answer (score 7):

Ugh. Another needless roadblock in the already painful experience of iOS development. Here's how I finally managed to fix this: Click on Edit to edit the bank information, then View/Edit details for the existing account. Without changing anything, click Next and Save. Then you gotta wait 24 hours, even though you didn't change anything hahaha!

Comment: I'd say this is a needful problem. Apple has to obey tax laws and rules to run their store. If you choose to have Apple sell your app, there are rules and hoops and systems you need to satisfy to do so.

Comment: This worked, however I had to add a space after our company name in order to save. It wouldn't let me save without  it.

Answer (score 5):

Check your contracts are in order at iTunes Connect. Apple won't publish apps until you've accepted the contracts.

When you log in to iTunes Connect, the main page will state something like "The following contracts are expired: iOS Paid Applications. This could be affecting the availability of your apps. To request and complete your updated contracts, go to the Contracts, Tax, and Banking module."

Comment: well, it says in Contracts tax and banking that the IOS dev program membership is expired, but it is NOT expired, since I renewed it. And on member center side it says it is expiring on feb 2014... Not a happy customer.